# PDFBox 0.7.3 convert pdf to text

Tags: c#, itext, pdfbox, pdftotext

I want to convert pdf file to text file but some of pdf files do not work with pdfbox dll as the version of acrobat in newer than Acrobat 5.x

Please tell me what i do?

```
output.WriteLine("Begin Parsing.....");
output.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());

PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(path);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

output.Write(stripper.getText(doc));
```

Comment: Why did you tag this question with the tag itextsharp? Your question is only about PDFBox...

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt should be to try with a current version of PDFBox. Your version 0.7.3 dates back to **2006!** PDFBox meanwhile has become an Apache project and is located [here: http://pdfbox.apache.org/](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) and the current version (as of May 2013) is 1.8.1. And I'm very sure that PDFBox nowerdays does support PDF object streams and cross reference streams which were new in PDF Reference version 1.5, the version Adobe Acrobat 6 has been built for

If that does not work, you might want to try other PDF libraries, e.g. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (or iTextSharp in your case) version 5.4.x if the AGPL (or alternatively buying a license) is no problem for you.

Information on text parsing using iText(Sharp) can be found in chapter15 *Marked content and parsing PDF* of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/index.php). The samples from that chapter can be found online: [Java](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=15) and [.Net](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/).

For a first test the sample [ExtractPageContentSorted2.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter15&ex=ExtractPageContentSorted2) / [ExtractPageContentSorted2.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=296) would be a good start. The central code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDF_FILE);
PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
    sb.AppendLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
}
```

If neither a current PDFBox version nor a current iText(Sharp) version can parse your PDF, you might want to post a sample for inspection; there are ways to drop all information required for text parsing from a PDF...

Comment: Correct, you asked for *text* after all, nor for *rich text* or *formatted text* or something along those lines. Furthermore your sample using the PDFBox PDFTextStripper does not show formatting either when I test it against some documents here.

Comment: I want to check if pdf file contain text (any text not specific) I see many answer for specific text which i don't need, I used this code System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
                            string fileContent = Reader.ReadToEnd();


                            if (fileContent.Contains(" "))
                            {

                                } contains must take any think but i want test if pdf has any text .

Comment: Well, if you can check file contents, you surely also can check `StringBuilder` contents... I would propose removing white spaces first, though. As for your test you could actually stop parsing page contents as soon as any text at all pops up, you do not even need to collect all text in the `StringBuilder` but can instead inspect the string returned for each page immediately after extraction and stop as soon as any text is there. You could optimize even more by using a custom`text extration strategy which only returns whether some text is contained ot not...

Comment: I didn't use string builder it takes long time ,I use  StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(newpath, FileMode.Create));output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));my code read only pdf contain text i don't need read pdf which has only image,for that i check if contain any text

Comment: Ok @DinaJarrah, so now which problem remains? You have all the building blocks available. Simply put them together.

Comment: Now I test the above code in new folder of PDF but there are some problem not all pdf files convert.

Comment: Some PDFs do not contain enough information for text extraction short of ocr, some even contain misleading informations.  I would need the PDF itself to tell why text extraction fails for it.

Comment: how add folder for you see

Comment: I used pdfbox 1.2.1 convert correct just one folder convert in above code but now not convert and some problem appeare when i check the length of file it take o byte but file contain info i used new FileInfo(newpath)).ToString()

Comment: this code PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(path);
                                PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

                                output.Write(stripper.getText(doc));

Comment: and above problem in also this code PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path); the file size of under 5k the length of it 0 byte

Comment: As this looks like a different issue altogether, please make it a question in its own right and provide enough source code to reproduce it.

Comment: Could you tell me why when I check the file length(if contain any text) it give me 0 byte althogh the size of file not 0 this problem just in the files which length under 5kB i used new FileInfo(newpath).Length

Comment: I cannot tell you for sure because you do not provide enough code to reproduce the issue. A wild guess would be, though, that you do not flush or close your `output` before checking the length of the file.

Comment: I convert pdf file to text and store text file I want to check if empty or not I used output befor check

Comment: I convert pdf file to text and store text file I want to check if empty or not I used output befor check (if (new FileInfo(newpath).Length == 0)) some file contain data but when check take me the length is zero this problem in files which size on disc under 5 byte

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have file with 143KB size when I check the length above short code give 0 byte just this problem