# PDFParser error message

Tags: c#, pdfbox, pdftotext

**Error 1**

> The best overloaded method match for 'org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.PDFParser(java.io.InputStream)' has some invalid arguments   H:\pdf_ver3.cs  129 51  PDF-to-Text Convertor

**Code:**

```
PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();
pdfParser.ExtractText(path, newpath);
```

Comment: PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();
                            pdfParser.ExtractText(path, newpath);

Comment: You are using PDFBox. Why do you tag it as iTextSharp related? Furthermore the error looks Java-ish (referencing `java.io.InputStream`), not C#-ish

Comment: yes I used PDFBox as reference

Comment: But neither is your error message iTextSharp-related (it explicitly references `org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.PDFParser` and therefore obviously PDFBox-related) nor is your code line (there is no class named `PDFParser` in iTextSharp).

Comment: I used in my code using org.pdfbox.pdfparser;

Comment: Is the `PDFParser` class in your code line from the namespace `org.pdfbox.pdfparser` or is it from a different one? I ask because the `PDFParser` class from `org.pdfbox` does not have a constructor without argument...

Comment: what type of this argument,I use windows form not console.no class for PDFParser

Comment: Read the error message: `java.io.InputStream` --- @Templar in his answer seems to try to point you to where you retrieve that stream object.

Comment: I want to convert pdf file to text file but some of pdf files do not work with pdfbox dll as the version of acrobat in newer than Acrobat 5.x,for that I want to use PDFParser.

Comment: this is code PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(path);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

output.Write(stripper.getText(doc));

Comment: *"I want to convert pdf file to text file but some of pdf files do not work with pdfbox dll as the version of acrobat in newer than Acrobat 5.x,for that I want to use PDFParser"* --- then why don't you create a question on stack overflow concerning this?

Comment: I create one but there is no any answerhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/16374746/pdfbox-0-7-3-convert-pdf-to-text

Comment: Ok, considering that the original tags of that question were *c#, html,* and *visual-studio-2010* that's not surprising... BTW, the title of that question already gives quite a hint: PDFBox 0.7.3 is ancient, it has been published 2006!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the inputstream from the document to the constructor.

Comment: using org.pdfbox.pdmodel;
using org.pdfbox.util;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using org.pdfbox.pdfparser;    string filetext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + ".txt";
                        string newpath = Path.GetFullPath(path).Replace(Path.GetFileName(path), filetext); PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser(filename);
                            pdfParser.ExtractText(path, newpath);